# Unit test to check for ungenerated migrations

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-migrations

Has anyone written a unit test to verify if there are ungenerated migrations in their Django app? I think it should probably look something like:

1. Call `python manage.py makemigrations`
2. scrape results into a parsable object
3. verify `"no migrations were found"`
4. if migrations are found list them, fail the test, and delete the generated files

If not, I am going to write one so that we fail our build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick — no scraping.

It will show names of migrations, but when in doubt you still need to view `changes` in debugger.

```
class MigrationsCheck(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        from django.utils import translation
        self.saved_locale = translation.get_language()
        translation.deactivate_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        if self.saved_locale is not None:
            from django.utils import translation
            translation.activate(self.saved_locale)

    def test_missing_migrations(self):
        from django.db import connection
        from django.apps.registry import apps
        from django.db.migrations.executor import MigrationExecutor
        executor = MigrationExecutor(connection)
        from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
        from django.db.migrations.state import ProjectState
        autodetector = MigrationAutodetector(
            executor.loader.project_state(),
            ProjectState.from_apps(apps),
        )
        changes = autodetector.changes(graph=executor.loader.graph)
        self.assertEqual({}, changes)
```

Answer (score 9):

Since Django 1.10 the `makemigrations` management command has included a `--check` option. The command will exit with a non-zero status if migrations are missing.

Usage example:

```
./manage.py makemigrations --check --dry-run
```

Documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-makemigrations-check

Answer (score 2):

I would instead use the [--dry-run flag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---dry-run) and test that it is empty.

Comment: Ah, great idea, I did not realize this existed. I will update your answer with the test code I come up with

Answer (score 0):

You can steal some code from https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py#L68. Migrating to newer django versions might require some extra 5 min after that